# StaticInjectorError when adding simple provider to blank Ionic project and injecting into a component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm getting the following error when injecting a basic provider into the home page component of a blank Ionic project:

```
columnNumber: 19752
fileName: "http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js"
lineNumber: 3
message: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[TestProvider]: \n  StaticInjectorError[TestProvider]: \n    NullInjectorError: No provider for TestProvider!\n_NullInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1276:19\nresolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1564:17\ntryResolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1506:16\nStaticInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:20\nresolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1564:17\ntryResolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1506:16\nStaticInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:20\nresolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10938:12\nNgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12159:16\nresolveDep@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12655:12\ncreateClass@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12519:85\ncreateDirectiveInstance@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12364:37\ncreateViewNodes@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13802:53\ncreateRootView@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13692:5\ncallWithDebugContext@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15093:39\ndebugCreateRootView@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14394:12\nComponentFactory_.prototype.create@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11313:37\nComponentFactoryBoundToModule.prototype.create@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4275:16\nNavControllerBase.prototype._viewInit@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48293:27\nNavControllerBase.prototype._nextTrns/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48106:17\nF</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14974\nonInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:24\nF</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14901\nF</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10124\nf/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20240\nF</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649\nonInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24\nF</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562\nF</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815\no@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887\n"
promise: Object { __zone_symbol__state: 0, __zone_symbol__value: Error }
rejection: Error: StaticInjectorError[TestProvider]: 
  StaticInjectorError[TestProvider]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TestProvider!
Stack trace:
_NullInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1276:19
resolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1564:17
tryResolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1506:16
StaticInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:20
resolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1564:17
tryResolveToken@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1506:16
StaticInjector.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1377:20
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10938:12
NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12159:16
resolveDep@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12655:12
createClass@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12519:85
createDirectiveInstance@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12364:37
createViewNodes@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13802:53
createRootView@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13692:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15093:39
debugCreateRootView@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14394:12
ComponentFactory_.prototype.create@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11313:37
ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.prototype.create@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4275:16
NavControllerBase.prototype._viewInit@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48293:27
NavControllerBase.prototype._nextTrns/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48106:17
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14974
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:24
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14901
F</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10124
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20240
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887
stack: "c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752\nu/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19174\nNavControllerBase.prototype._fireError@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48075:13\nNavControllerBase.prototype._failed@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48068:9\nNavControllerBase.prototype._nextTrns/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:48115:53\nF</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14974\nonInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:24\nF</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14901\nF</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10124\nf/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20240\nF</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649\nonInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24\nF</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562\nF</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815\no@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887\n"
task: Object { runCount: 0, _state: "notScheduled", type: "microTask", … }
zone: Object { _properties: {…}, _parent: {…}, _name: "angular", … }
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a test project. `ionic start TestProject blank`
2. Add a test provider. `ionic generate provider TestProvider`. The provider is added to the provider list in the app.module.
3. Inject the provider into the home page component, by importing TestProvider and injecting into the constructor.
4. Sometimes the error occurs; sometimes it doesn't. If it doesn't, create another provider and repeat the process until the error occurs.

At one point, I created three separate test providers with identical, copy/pasted code; one of them worked consistently, but the other two produced the StaticInjectorError.

**TestProject/src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TestProvider } from '../providers/test/test';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    TestProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**TestProject/src/pages/home/home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TestProvider } from '../../providers/test/test';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public test: TestProvider ) {
  }
}
```

**TestProject/src/providers/test/test.js**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestProvider {

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello TestProvider Provider');
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ProviderNamingBug",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I'm running on Windows 10, with Node.js version 8.9.4 and npm version 5.6.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.